# Ruby: Convert BST time to UTC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, activerecord, time

```
script/console

>> t = Time.at(1158609371)
=> Mon Sep 18 20:56:11 +0100 2006
>> t.zone
=> "BST"
>> s = Shop.find(:first)
>> s.creation_tsz = t.utc
=> Mon Sep 18 19:56:11 UTC 2006
>> s.creation_tsz.zone
=> "UTC"
>> s.save
>> s = Shop.find(:first)
>> s.creation_tsz
=> Sat Jan 01 19:56:11 UTC 2000
```

How come it changed from Sep 18 2006 to Jan 01 2000? Timezone is setup to use "UTC" in environment.rb. And just so you are aware I have tried numerous variations of line `s.creation_tsz = t.utc` . All with failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that in the database, `s.creation_tsz` stores only a time, but not a date part, for example a [MySQL TIME type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html), as opposed to the [TIMESTAMP or DATETIME type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html).

Comment: changed data type from time to datetime. Fixed. Thanks